# socket.io-stream 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, socket.io, stream

I have installed socket.io-stream into my node_modules folder which is in my project directory but when I call :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/socket.io-stream.js"></script>
```

I get these errors in the Console:

```
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io-stream.js 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io-stream.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

What can I do to resolve this? I have checked to make sure it is in the correct directory and moved it to other directories with no luck.

The file I have this in is an html file not Node js so I cannot use express.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is not serving serverside files to the client by default. If it would do so, people could access your whole codebase including configs etc., so that wouldn't be good. Instead, you have to work with the request that comes in at the `http` module as an event, and answer it with the files content. To do so, you probably want to install the famous Express module (`npm install --save express`) and use its static file serving:

```
const Express = require("express");

const app = Express();

app.use(Express.static(__dirname + "/somestaticfolder"));
app.listen(80);
```

Now just put your file into `/somestaticfolder` and you are done.

[Docs](http://expressjs.com/de/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: The file I am doing this in is an html file not a Node js file